# Infering population from a sample?

Tags: sample, population

I took a test in class and found it to be difficult. So I asked in my WhatsApp group if others felt the same. 4/36 people replied yes they felt it difficult. Others did not respond either in yes or no. They may reply later. Can I infer anything about the whole class from this response. How to start a statistical approach to analyzing this situation about how the class felt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't infer anything about the whole class from the people who responded because the people who responded are almost certainly not a random sample from your class. They are probably a biased sample, although the direction of the bias may depend on exactly how you worded the question.

For instance if you ask:

> I found the recent test to be difficult. Did you?  (YES/NO)

you may get different answers from a question like:

> Did you find the recent test difficult?  (YES/NO)

or from

> How did you find the recent test (EASY/DIFFICULT)

Comment: How did you find the recent test (EASY/DIFFICULT)...Will this be a unbiased question?

Comment: An unbiased question of what? That is, you have to define some gold standard against which to judge bias.